# Detect the presence of Math to process in MathJax

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I am using MathJax and I have the following scenario:

> I want to run some code when the page contains some Math that MathJax will process and render properly

Consider this example:

```html
<p>
This is a page containing an equation: $b^2 - 4ac$.
</p>
```

Here the function, or whatever it is I can use, would return `true`. But if the page contains no chunk of TeX code to process (or any code according to how MathJax was configured to trigger), then this API would return `false`.

#### A bit more details

This is not about modifying the rendering pipeline. MathJax will eventually do its job and I am fine with it. I just need a reliable way (hopefully provided by the library's API) to detect that the page has some math that will need processing.

Does MathJax has a functionality that I can use to get this info? Also, for completeness, I am adding the way I am configuring MathJax (inline):

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/CommonHTML"],
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
      processEscapes: true
    },
    "CommonHTML": { linebreaks: { automatic: true } }
  });
</script>
<script src="//mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
```

#### Alternatively...

If what I am asking is not actually feasible, then how about this:

> Can I attach to an event in the rendering pipeline so I get to execute a callback function when MathJax is done rendering the math?

I saw the [MathJax startup sequence](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/startup.html) and there lies my answer probably. However I see the trigger is run also when there is no math on the page.

---

#### Troubleshoot

I have tried to detect the presence of classes like `MathJax_Preview` or `mjx-chtml` which are added to the elements that are generated. But this code is not reliable as it needs to trigger after the rendering process. And this adds time to the computation.

I cound not find the API I am looking for for querying the presence of math to render, but it seems strange there is not such a thing exposed by MathJax.

Comment: how about check the script tags if one of them references mathjax ?

Comment: I always have them on the page. It would always return `true`.

Comment: Your "alternatively" surprised me a bit. Usually this question comes up because people don't want to load MathJax when there's no math. Is the alternative the real question?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger: Looking back at it, you are right. My problem is basically that I do not want to load MathJax if no math is on the page. But it is a lso a bit more complicated. You see, I have some special code which listens to the `ersize` event on page in order to rerender the math by calling MathJax. This ensures that my math always fits in the page wrapping correctly. However I do not want to attach the event on resize (costly from UI perspective) if no math is on the page...

Comment: [This sample from the MathJax repository](https://cdn.rawgit.com/mathjax/MathJax/2.7.5/test/sample-signals.html) shows how to intercept the `New Math` signal. To not load MathJax, the only reliable way is to build a modification of the tex2jax pre-processor. Here's a [MathJax-independent copy](https://github.com/pkra/mathjax-node-page/blob/master/lib/tex.js) that might help to build upon.

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround is to create your own class, then test if this class is present in the DOM, then embed mathjax dynamically if needed

Snippet with math :

```js
var test  = document.querySelectorAll('.math2Process');

if(test.length>0){
  var mathJax_config = document.createElement('script');
  mathJax_config.setAttribute('type','text/x-mathjax-config');
  mathJax_config.text = `MathJax.Hub.Config({
      extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
      jax: ["input/TeX", "output/CommonHTML"],
      tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
        displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
        processEscapes: true
      },
      "CommonHTML": { linebreaks: { automatic: true } }
    });`
  var mathJax_script = document.createElement('script');

  mathJax_script.setAttribute('src','//mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML');

  document.head.appendChild(mathJax_config);
  document.head.appendChild(mathJax_script);
}
```

```html
<p class="math2Process">
This is a page containing an equation: $b^2 - 4ac$.
</p>
```

the same but no math :

```js
var test  = document.querySelectorAll('.math2Process');

if(test.length>0){
  var mathJax_config = document.createElement('script');
  mathJax_config.setAttribute('type','text/x-mathjax-config');
  mathJax_config.text = `MathJax.Hub.Config({
      extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
      jax: ["input/TeX", "output/CommonHTML"],
      tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
        displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
        processEscapes: true
      },
      "CommonHTML": { linebreaks: { automatic: true } }
    });`
  var mathJax_script = document.createElement('script');

  mathJax_script.setAttribute('src','//mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML');

  document.head.appendChild(mathJax_config);
  document.head.appendChild(mathJax_script);
}
```

```html
<p>
This is a page containing an equation: $b^2 - 4ac$.
</p>
```

Comment: This is a valid alternative, though I do not like it as it complicates a bit the flow, it is definitely a solution. Thanks I will consider it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will check if the current page requires MathJax, and only load in the script if it is needed:

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const skipHtmlTags = ['script', 'noscript', 'style', 'textarea', 'pre', 'code', 'annotation', 'annotation-xml'].map((v) => `:not(${v})`).join('')
  const ignoreHtmlClasses = ['mathjax_ignore'].map((v) => `:not(.${v})`).join('')
  const requiresMathjax = Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll('*' + skipHtmlTags + ignoreHtmlClasses))
    .some((el) => el.textContent.match(/\\\(|\$\$|\\\[/))

  if (requiresMathjax) {
    const sc = document.createElement('script')
    sc.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/3.2.0/es5/tex-mml-chtml.min.js')
    sc.setAttribute('integrity', 'sha512-9DkJEmXbL/Tdj8b1SxJ4H2p3RCAXKsu8RqbznEjhFYw0cFIWlII+PnGDU2FX3keyE9Ev6eFaDPyEAyAL2cEX0Q==')
    sc.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous')
    sc.setAttribute('referrerpolicy', 'no-referrer')
    document.head.appendChild(sc)
  }
})
</script>
```

minified:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{var t=["script","noscript","style","textarea","pre","code","annotation","annotation-xml"].map(t=>`:not(${t})`).join(""),e=["mathjax_ignore"].map(t=>`:not(.${t})`).join("");if(Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll("*"+t+e)).some(t=>t.textContent.match(/\\\(|\$\$|\\\[/))){const n=document.createElement("script");n.setAttribute("src","https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/3.2.0/es5/tex-mml-chtml.min.js"),n.setAttribute("integrity","sha512-9DkJEmXbL/Tdj8b1SxJ4H2p3RCAXKsu8RqbznEjhFYw0cFIWlII+PnGDU2FX3keyE9Ev6eFaDPyEAyAL2cEX0Q=="),n.setAttribute("crossorigin","anonymous"),n.setAttribute("referrerpolicy","no-referrer"),document.head.appendChild(n)}});
```

You have `inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],`, but you probably will want to stop using just a single dollar sign--you'll get too many false-positives. If you want to keep using a single dollar sign, you can update the regex in the script.

If you'd like a different script, update the `src` and `integrity` attributes using the URLs at https://cdnjs.com/libraries/mathjax (or your preferred CDN)